# Probability for drawing four cards of different ranks using binomial coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics

An exercise requires me to solve the probability for drawing four cards of different ranks $(A)$. This is my solution:

$
P(A) = \frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{44}{50} \cdot \frac{40}{49} \approx 0.68
$

This is enough to satisfy the exercise's requirements. However, I would like to learn to solve this with binomial coefficients. My intuition, since there exist four cards of each rank, was

$
P(A) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}^4}{\binom{52}{4}},
$

which does not appear to be correct. I.e., my problem is not understanding how to count the number of different hands that consist of different ranks. How should I think about this in terms of combinatorics?

Comment: Hint:  In the numerator you are missing the number of ways of picking the 4 ranks

Comment: Thanks, @dm63, this helped me understand the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:
$$P(A)=\frac{{13 \choose 4} \cdot 4^4}{{52 \choose 4}}=\frac{48}{51} \cdot \frac{44}{50} \cdot \frac{40}{49} \approx 0.68$$
Because to choose four cards of a different rank you have to first pick $4$ ranks and then assign each of them a suit (since the ranks are different the suits can be arbirtary and no two will coincide).